# Refactor code to avoid circular logic in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

**Situation**:

- One form that allows users to select multiple quantities of items they'd like to request
- This form POSTs to two models, one parent: Request, and child: Items.
- Upon submit, one Request is created, but up to several Items are created, depending on the quantity indicated
- To handle this, I have two sets of params, one for the Items, one for Requests

**Desired end state**:

- I do not want an Item to be created without a Request nor a Request to be created without the Item
- All the errors present in the form (whether it's not selecting at least one item, or errors in the attributes of the Request object) are shown together to the user once the page is re-rendered; i.e., I would like to do all the error checking together

**Current hacky solution & complication**:

- Currently, I'm checking in stages, 1) are there quantities in the Items? If not, then regardless of what the user may have put for Request attributes, the page is re-rendered (i.e., all attributes for Request are lost, as are any validation errors that would be shown). 2) Once the first stage is passed, then the model validations kicks in, and if it fails, the new page is re-rendered again

I've spent waaaaay too long thinking about this, and nothing elegant comes to mind. Happy with the hacky solution, but would love insights from much smarter people!

**Controller code** (fat for now, will fix later)

```
def create

request_params
@requestrecord = @signup_parent.requests.build

if @itemparams.blank?
  @requestrecord.errors[:base] = "Please select at least one item"
  render 'new'
else
  @requestrecord = @signup_parent.requests.create(@requestparams)
  if @requestrecord.save
    items_to_be_saved = []
    @itemparams.each do |item, quantity|
    quantity = quantity.to_i
      quantity.times do
        items_to_be_saved << ({:request_id => 0, :name => item })
      end
    end
    Item.create items_to_be_saved
    flash[:success] = "Thanks!"
    redirect_to action: 'success'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
end

def request_params
  @requestparams = params.require(:request).permit(:detail, :startdate, :enddate) 
  @itemparams = params["item"]
  @itemparams = @transactionparams.first.reject { |k, v| (v == "0") || (v == "")}
end
```

And in case it's helpful, the snippet of the view code that generates the `params["item"]`

```
          <% itemlist.each do |thing| %>
            <%= number_field_tag "item[][#{thing}]", :quantity, min: 0, placeholder: 0 %>
            <%= label_tag thing %>
            </br>
          <% end %>
          <!-- itemlist is a variable in the controller that is populated with a list of items -->
```

Comment: The controller looks to be missing part to it. "items_to_be_saved" is never used anywhere and "item_to_be_saved" inside quantity.times appears to be a typo.

Comment: Just a quick typo. fixed!

Comment: You are building up items_to_be_saved but it is never used. Should transactions_to_be_saved be replaced with items_to_be_saved?

Comment: yes sorry typing too fast!

Answer (score 0):

**Validations**

When you mention you want all the errors to be returned at the same time, it basically means you need to use the Rails' [validations functionality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

This populates the `@model.errors` object, which you can then use on your `form` like this:

```
<% if @model.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
```

I think your problem is you're trying to use the validations in the controller. This is both against [MVC principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) & generally bad for programming modularity. The functionality you require is available with the `validations` features:

---

You may benefit from using [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aAssociations%3a%3aClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) to create some conditional validations; or using [`reject_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

**reject_if**

```
#app/models/request.rb
Class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['an_item_param'].blank? #-> attributes are the "item" attributes }
end
```

This will only be triggered if a request is created. I.E if your request fails for some reason (validation issue), the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method will not run, returning your object with the appended `errors`

This is mainly used to validate the nested resources (I.E you can't save an `item` unless its `title` attribute is populated etc)

--

**inverse_of**

```
#app/models/request.rb
Class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items, inverse_of: :request
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

#app/models/item.rb
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :request, inverse_of: :items
   validates :title, presence: true, unless: :draft?

   private

   def draft?
       self.request.draft #-> an example we've used before :)
   end
end
```

This is more for model-specific validations; allowing you to determine specific conditions. We use this if we want to save a draft etc

Comment: You know I went to sleep last night thinking Rich will probably get this when I wake up =). I do have a question though. The reason this was so hard for me... because I thought about using `accepted_nested_attributes` is because `items` isn't really an attribute. Like a Request has many Items, but an Item doesn't have an attribute other than it's name. And it's name is the `#{thing}` I'm already calling in the form, the only thing the user is inputting is the `quantity` variable. Would this work in that case?

Comment: Hi James, you're too kind! I just spend time on here each day to polish my skills. When you say `items` is not really an attribute - you're getting confused. `Accepts nested attributes` accepts attributes for a child *model*, meaning it doesn't matter which `attributes` you send, as long as the `Item` model is where they're headed

Comment: just so I'm clear, `accepts nested attributes` works even if I'm not sending any attributes? The user entered data is not an attribute in the child model, it's the quantity that represents the number of new child records I want to create.